# New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport does not accept a DatabaseMaxSizeBytes greater than 5GB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm trying to import a database from a .bacpac file using New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport in powershell. The database is about 8GB in size.  When I set the required parameter DatabaseMaxSizeBytes to any amount greater than 5GB, I receive the error:

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus : BadRequest: The ImportExport operation with 
Request Id 'a824a510-xxxxx' failed due to 'Error encountered during the service operation.
    Could not import package.
Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2008 as the target platform may 
experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 40619, Level 16, State 1, 
Line 1 The edition 'Premium' does not
support the database data max size '9663676416'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
(EDITION = 'Premium', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P1', MAXSIZE = 9 GB)
```

The command accepted a DatabaseMaxSizeBytes of 5GB but of course, the process failed when the import hit the 5GB ceiling.

The database import succeeds if I use the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest version of SQL PowerShell module from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-2017).

The following script works:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$userId = "MyEmail@MyEmail"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userId ,$password)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -TenantId "MyTenantID"

$sourceserver = "DBServer"
$sourceresourcegroupname = "ResourceGroupName"
$sourcedatabasename = "DBName"
$copyDatabaseName = "CopyDatabaseName"

$DBImport = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName $sourceresourcegroupname `
   -ServerName $sourceserver `
   -DatabaseName $sourcedatabasename `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "21474836480" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey $(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $sourceresourcegroupname -StorageAccountName devtestdatabase).Value[0] `
   -StorageUri "https://mystorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/testing/test.bacpac" `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "S9" `
   -AdministratorLogin "adminUserName" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "AdminPassword" -AsPlainText -Force)

While ((Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $DBImport.OperationStatusLink).Status -eq "InProgress")
{
    Sleep -Seconds 10   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This solved my problem.  I had spent a couple of hours searching the web and couldn't find a solution.